# AWS ECS: Monitoring the status of a service update

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to migrate a set of microservices from Docker Swarm, to AWS ECS using Fargate.

I have created an ECS cluster. Moreover, I have initialized repositories using the ECR, each of which contains an image of a microservice.

I have successfully came up with a way to create new images, and push them into the ECR. In fact, with each change in the code, a new docker image is built, tagged, and pushed.

Moreover, I have created a task definition that is linked to a service. This task definition contains one container, and all the necessary information. Moreover, its service defines that the task will run in a VPC, and is linked to a load balancer, and has a target group. I am assuming that every new deployment uses the image with the "latest" tag.

So far with what I have explained, everything is clear and is working well.

Below is the part that is confusing me. After every new build, I would like to update the service in order for new tasks with the update image get deployed. I am using the cli to do so with the following command:

`aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster-name> --service <service-name>`

Typically, after performing the command, I am monitoring the deployment logs, under the event tab, and checking the state of the service using the following command:

`aws ecs describe-services --cluster <cluster-name> --service <service-name>`

Finally, I tried to simulate a case where the newly created image contains a bad code. Thus, the new tasks will not be able to get deployed. What I have witnessed is that Fargate will keep trying (without stopping) to deploy the new tasks. Moreover, aside the event logs, the `describe-services` command does not contain relevant information, other than what Fargate is doing (e.g., registering/deregistering tasks). I am surprised that I could not find any mechanism that instructs Fargate, or the service to stop the deployment and rollback to the already existing one.

I found this article (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/automating-rollback-of-failed-amazon-ecs-deployments/ ), which provides a solution. However, it is a fairly complicated one, and assumes that each new deployment is triggered by a new task definition, which is not what I want.

Therefore, considering what I have described above, I hope you can answer the following questions:

1) Using CLI commands (For automation purposes) Is there a way to instruct Fargate to automatically stop the current deployment, after failing to deploy new tasks after a few tries?

2) Using the CLI commands, is there a way to monitor the current status of the deployment? For instance, when performing a service update on a service on Docker swarm, the terminal generates live logs on the update process

3) After a failed deployment, is there a way for Fargate to signal an error code, or flag, or message?

Comment: 1) Don't know. 2) The way I monitor Fargate is the CloudWatch logs 3) At a failed deployment, AWS HealthCheck would fail wouldn´t it? And that would show in the CloudWatch logs.

Answer (score 5):

As of now, you have a way to do this:

```
aws ecs wait services-stable --cluster MyCluster --services MyService
```

The previous example pauses and continues only after it can confirm that the service running on the cluster is stable. Will return `255` exit code after 40 failed checks.

To cancel a deployment, enable ECS Circuit Breaker when creating your service:

```
aws ecs create-service \
     --service-name MyService \
     --deployment-configuration "deploymentCircuitBreaker={enable=true,rollback=true}" \
     {...}
```

References:

- [Service deployment check.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/wait/services-stable.html)
- [Circuit Breaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/deployment-type-ecs.html)

Comment: Thanks for this, I was just looking to wait until latest deployment was finished. Only thing to add is you may need to add `--region <region>` to the commands.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, ECS does not offer deployment status directly. Once you issue a deployment, there is no way to determine its status other than to continually poll for updates until you have enough information to infer from them. Plus `unexpected container exits` are not logged anywhere. You have to search through failed tasks. The way I get them is by cloudwatch rule that triggers a lambda upon task state change.

I recommend you read: https://medium.com/@aaron.kaz.music/monitoring-the-health-of-ecs-service-deployments-baeea41ae737

Answer (score 0):

You can now get this information through [`aws ecs describe-services`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/describe-services.html).

The CLI command responds with a JSON object that has a `deployments` list. The 0th index of that list will contain a `rolloutState` key:

> The rollout state of the deployment. When a service deployment is started, it begins in an `IN_PROGRESS` state. When the service reaches a steady state, the deployment transitions to a `COMPLETED` state. If the service fails to reach a steady state and circuit breaker is turned on, the deployment transitions to a `FAILED` state. A deployment in `FAILED` state doesn't launch any new tasks. For more information, see DeploymentCircuitBreaker .

Using `jq`, you can select the `rolloutState` like this:

```
aws ecs describe-services --cluster "$ECS_CLUSTER" --services "$ECS_SERVICE" | jq -rc '.services[0].deployments[0].rolloutState'
```

Make sure to put in your cluster arn/name and service name in place of the variables. This should output a plaintext value of `IN_PROGRESS`, `COMPLETED`, or `FAILED`.

To wait for the deployment to finish, wrap it into a loop and evaluate the output:

```bash
unknown_deploy_status_counter=0
while true; do
  SERVICE_STATUS=$(aws ecs describe-services --cluster "$ECS_CLUSTER" --services "$ECS_SERVICE")
  DEPLOYMENT_STATUS=$(echo "$SERVICE_STATUS" | jq -rc '.services[0].deployments[0].status')
  ROLLOUT_STATE=$(echo "$SERVICE_STATUS" | jq -rc '.services[0].deployments[0].rolloutState')
  ROLLOUT_STATE_REASON=$(echo "$SERVICE_STATUS" | jq -rc '.services[0].deployments[0].rolloutStateReason')
  
  # Tell user what's going on
  >&2 echo "Deployment Status: $DEPLOYMENT_STATUS"
  >&2 echo "Deployment Rollout State: $ROLLOUT_STATE"
  >&2 echo "Deployment Rollout State Reason: $ROLLOUT_STATE_REASON"
  >&2 echo ""

  case "$ROLLOUT_STATE" in
    "COMPLETED")
      >&2 echo "Deployment completed successfully"
      break
      ;;
    "FAILED")
      >&2 echo "Deployment failed"
      exit 1
      ;;
    "IN_PROGRESS")
      : # Do nothing
      ;;
    *)
      ((unknown_deploy_status_counter++))
      >&2 echo "Unknown deployment status. Rechecking."
      if [ "$unknown_deploy_status_counter" -gt 12 ]; then
        >&2 echo "Deployment status has been unknown for 12 checks. Something is probably wrong, check the AWS Console for more info."
        exit 1
      fi
      ;;
  esac
  sleep 10
done
```